# What is the most convincing way to require formalized unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, software-quality

This certainly presupposes that unit testing is a good thing. Our projects have some level of unit testing, but it's inconsistent at best.

What are the most convincing ways that you have used or have had used with you to convince everyone that formalized unit testing is a good thing and that making it required is really in the best interest of the 'largeish' projects we work on. I am not a developer, but I am in Quality Assurance and would like to improve the quality of the work delivered to ensure it is ready to test.

By formalized unit tests, I'm simply talking about

- Identifying the Unit Tests to be written
- Identifying the test data (or describe it)
- Writing these tests
- Tracking these tests (and re-using as needed)
- Making the results available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, two years after I asked this question, I find that one unexpected answer was that by moving to a new SDLC was what was needed. Five years ago, we established our first formal SDLC. It improved our situation, but left out some important things, such as automation. We are now in the process of establishing a new SDLC (under new managment) where one of the tenants is automation. Not just automated unit tests, but automated functional tests.

I guess the lesson is that I was thinking too small. If you are going to change how you create software, go 'whole hog' and make a drastic change rather than propose incremental change if you are not used to that.

Answer (score 4):

A very convincing way is to do formalized unit test yourself, regardless of what your team/company does. This might take some extra effort on your side, especially if you're not experienced with this sort of practice.

When you can then show your code is better and you are being more productive than your fellow developers, they are going to want to know why. Then feed them your favorite unit testing methods.

Once you've convinced your fellow developers, convince management together.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) with the [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) and [Cobertura](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) plugins for all my builds. The actual test cases are created with [JUnit](http://junit.org), [DbUnit](http://dbunit.org) and [EasyMock](http://easymock.org).

**Identifying Unit Tests**
I try to follow Test Driven Development but to be honest I usually just do that for the handful of the test cases and then come back and create tests for the edge and exception cases later.

**Identifying Test Data**
DbUnit is great for loading test data for your unit tests.

**Writing Test Cases**
I use JUnit to create the test cases. I try to write self documenting test cases but will use Javadocs to comment something that is not obvious.

**Tracking & Making The Results Available**
I integrate the unit testing into my Maven build cycle using the Surefire plugin and I use the Corbertura plugin to measure the coverage achieved by those tests. I always generate and publish a web-site including the Surefire and Cobertura reports as part of my daily build so I can see what tests failed/passed.

Answer (score 2):

The event which convinced me was when we managed to regress a bug three times, in three consecutive releases. Once I realised how much more productive I was as a programmer when I wasn't constantly fixing trivial mistakes after they had gone to the client, and I could have a warm fuzzy feeling that colleagues code would do what they claimed it would, I became a convert.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I did Cobol development on Mainframes we did this religiously in the several companies I worked in and it was accepted as the way you did things because the environment enforced it.  I think it was a very typical scheme for the era and maybe some of the reasons might be applicable to you:-

Like most mainframe environments we had three realms, development, Quality Assurance and Production.  Programmers developed in development and unit tested there, and once they signed off and were happy the unit was migrated to the QA environment (with the test and results docs) where it was system tested by dedicated QA staff.  The development to QA migration was a formal step which happened overnight.  Once QA'ed the code was migrated to Production - and we had very few bugs.

The motivation to get the unit testing done and right was that if you didn't and a bug was found by QA staff it was obvious that you hadn't done the work.  Consequently your reputation depended on how rigorous you were.  Of course most people would end up with the occasional bug, but coders who produced solid tested code all the time soon got a star reputation and those who produced buggy code got noticed too.  The push would be always to up your game, and consequently the culture produced was one that pushed towards bug free code delivered first time.

Extracting pertinent points -

1. Coder reputation tied up with delivery of bug free tested code
2. Significant overhead associated with moving unit tested code to the next level, so motivation not to repeat this and get it right first time.
3. System testing performed by different people to unit testing - ideally a different team.

I'm sure your environment will differ but the principals might be translatable.

Answer (score 1):

Education and/or certification.

Give your team members a formal training in the field of testing - maybe with certification exam (depending on your team members and your own attitude towards certification). You'll take testing to a higher level that way, and your team members will be more likely to take a professional attitude towards testing.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes by example is the best way. I also find that reminding people that certain things just dont happen when things are under test. Next time somebody asks you to write something, do it with tests regardless. Eventually your peers will be jealous of the ease by which you can change your code and know that it still works.

As for management you need to emphasise how much time gets wasted due to the nuclear explosion that occurs when you need to make a change to codebase X that isnt under test.

Many developers dont realise just how much they refactor without ensuring they are preserving behaviour across the entire system. For me this is the biggest benefit to unit testing and TDD in my opinion.

1. Software requirements change
2. Software changes to suit the requirements

The only certainty is change. Changing code that is not under test requires the developer to be aware of every behavioural side effect possible. The reality is that the coders who think they can read into every permutation, does so by a pain staking process of trial and error until nothing breaks obviously. At this point they check in.

The pragmatic programmer recognizes that he/she is not perfect and all knowing, and that tests are like a safety net that allows them to walk the refactoring tightrope quickly and safely.

As for when to write test on greenfield code, I'd have to advocate as much as possible. Spend the time defining the *behaviours* that you want out of your system and write tests initially to express those higher level constructs. Unit tests can come as thoughts crystallize.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between **convincing** and **requiring**.

If you find a way to convince your colleagues to write them - great. However if you create some formalized rules and require them to write unit tests, they will find a way to overcome this. As a result you will get a bunch of unit tests which are worth nothing: There will be unit test for every single class available and they will test setters and getters.

Think twice before creating and enforcing rules. Developers are good at overcoming them.

Answer (score 0):

Remind your team or the other developers that they're professionals, not amateurs. Worked for me!

Also, it's an industry standard these days. Without unit testing experience, they are less desirable and less valuable as employees to potential future employers.

Answer (score 0):

First time around you just need to go ahead and write them and show people that it's worth it.  I've found on three projects that it's the only way to convince people.  Some people who don't code (e.g. junior project managers) won't be able to see the value until it's staring them right in the face.

Answer (score 0):

On my software team, we tend to write a small business case on these issues and present them to management in order to have the time available to create and track tests. We explain that the time taken to test is well made up for when crunch time comes and everything is on the line. We also set up a Hudson build server to centralize the tracking of the unit tests. This makes it a lot easier for the developers to keep track of failing tests and to discover recurring problems.

Answer (score 0):

As a team lead, it is my responsibility to ensure that my programmers are doing unit testing on all the modules they work on.  I suppose at this point, it's not even a question of how to convince them, it's required.  Not sometimes, not on largish projects, all the time.  Unit testing is the first line of defense against putting something in production that you will have to maintain.  If something is put into production that has not been completely unit and system tested, then it will come back to bite you.  I guess one of the policies we have here to support this is that if it blows in production, or causes problems, then the programmer responsible for coding and testing that module will be the one that has to take care of the problems, do the cleanup, etc.  That alone is a fairly good motivator.
The other is that it is about pride.  I work in a shop of about 75 coders, although that is large by some standards, it's really small enough for all of us to know one another.  Its also small enough that we know what one another is working on, and when it does move to production, we are aware of any abends, failures, etc.  If you are careful, do the unit and system testing, the chances of moving something to production without causing failures increases significantly.  It may take a time or two of moving something to production and failing to realize it, but there are great rewards involved in not messing up.  It's really nice to hear congratulations in the hallway when you move a project in and it doesn't screw up.

Answer (score 0):

Write a bunch of them and demonstrate that unit testing has improved your productivity and the quality of your code. Without some kind of proof, sometimes people won't believe it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take some inspiration from an initiative at Google. Their test team started putting up examples, tips and benefits inside the toilet cubicles to raise the profile of the merits of test automation.

https://testing.googleblog.com/2007/01/introducing-testing-on-toilet.html